# Ethereum Undecodable logs

Tags: go-ethereum, events, logs, event-handling, topics

I have encountered this [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x495402df7d45fe36329b0bd94487f49baee62026d50f654600f6771bd2a596ab#eventlog) where all of its logs were undecodable.
If you see the value of topic0 in events logs, it is function signature but ideally it should be the event signature. From where the event gets emitted.

Can someone explain me why its like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [Solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#events):

> Solidity events represent an abstraction over the EVM logging
> functionality.

Under the hood, Solidity uses the low-level [EVM opcodes](https://www.evm.codes/) `LOG`.

The [contract](https://github.com/makerdao/osm/blob/48a9ad934f7cc791b85fb336e4140c1ef36ad8db/src/osm.sol#L31-L47) directly accesses the `LOG4` opcode and decides not to log the [event signature](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html#events).